# how to append more than one button with different id to a div by creating a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

My task is to append button dynamically to a div .. and i want to apppend more than one button with different id to a single or different div by using a simple function. the below code that i have to used to append single button to a div..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    addInputTo($(".myClass"));
    $("#field").click(function () {
        alert("hi");
        $(".myClass").appendTo({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-locked"
            },
        });
    });

});

function addInputTo(container) {
    var inputToAdd = $("<input/>", {
        type: "button",
        id: "field",
        value: "Test Button"
    });
    // var s="trype='button";
    container.append(inputToAdd);
}

</script>


<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Is there any solution to append more than one button by creating single function like..

```
_app.CreateButton (id, text, primaryIcon, secondaryIcon, className);
```

please help me

and we use the below code to append icon to button but it dosen't work please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function runEffect() {
  debugger;
  alert("1");
  $( ".AdvSearchSaveButton" ).button({
    icons: {
      primary: "ui-icon-locked"
    },   
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filed").click(function () {
    alert("hi");
    runEffect();
    //  $( "#filed" ).addClass( "ui-icon-locked" );

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is primary and secondaryIcon variables

Comment: variables used to append icons to button

Answer (score 1):

you can change the function `addInputTo` to

```
function addInputTo(container, id, text){
            var inputToAdd = $("<input/>", { type: "button", id: id, value: text });
            container.append(inputToAdd);
}
```

then call it using

```
addInputTo($(".myClass"), 'filed', 'test button');
```

Comment: please clarify.. i can't catch it

Comment: is there any solution to append icons to button onclick? by using the same function as above

Answer (score 0):

This is really all you need. I just tied the event handler to the click of any `<div>` with the class = "myClass" with a self calling function.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="myClass" style="width:150px; height:150px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var id=0;

$(function(){
    $(".myClass").click(function(){
        id++;
        var newButton = "<input type='button' id='number" + id.toString() + "'value='test button'></input>";
        $(this).append(newButton);
    });
});
```

Just click on your `<div>` and a new button with a unique id will be appended to the `<div>`. Cheers!